# default Sms composer with attachment android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mms

I want to send a sms with an attachment i.e. image or video. It is working correctly for small images but when the size of image is more than 160k, it shows message "picture too large compressing.." but not opening sms composer after that. I am using samsung grand 4.2. It is working correctly in other devices.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(items.get(j).getAttachmentPath())));                             
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: a sms cannot have an attachment.. you probably want to send a mms with an attachment

Comment: Ok can you please provide me code for mms